# How to integrate hadoop with zookeeper and hbase

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have set up a single node cluster of Hadoop 2.6 but i need to integrate zookeeper and hbase with it.
I am a beginner with no prior experience in big data tools.
How do you set up zookeeper to coordinate hadoop cluster and how do we use hbase over hdfs?
How do they combine to make a ecosystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standalone mode, just follow the steps provided in this HBase guide:http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart

HBase has a standalone mode that makes it easy for starters to get going. In standalone mode hbase,hdfs, and zk runs in single JVM process.

Comment: so you just install hbase it will automatically integrate with hdfs. or it will detect automatically that hadoop is installed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of system that you want to build. As you said, the Hadoop ecosystem is made my three major components: HBase, HDFS, and zookeeper. Although they can be installed independently from each other, sometimes there is no need to install them all depending on the kind of cluster that you want to setup.

Since you are using a single node cluster, there are two HBase run modes that you can choose: the standalone mode and the pseudo-distributed mode. In the standalone mode there is no need to install HDFS or Zookeeper. HBase will do everything in a transparent way. If you want to use the pseudo-distributed mode, you can run HBase against the local filesystem or against HDFS. If you want to use HDFS, you'll have to install Hadoop. About the zookeeper, again, the HBase will also do the job by itself (you just need to tell him that through the configuration files).

In case you want to use HDFS in the pseudo-distributed mode, downloading Hadoop you will get HDFS and MapReduce. If you don't want to execute MapReduce jobs, just ignore its tools.

If you want to learn more, I think that this guide explains it all very well: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html (check the HBase run modes).